# How to route to different implementations according to whether an object is a rvalue reference or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, rvalue-reference, stdmove

For example, I have a class called `MyClass` and create an instance from it:

```
auto obj = MyClass()
```

I have two ways to call its method.

Option 1: call the method directly

```
obj.method()
```

Option 2: cast `obj` to rvalue reference first, then call the method

```
std::move(obj).method()
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to create different implementation of `method` between Option 1 and Option 2. Is there a way to route/overload the method according to whether an object is a rvalue reference or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare member functions with [reference qualifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions). e.g.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void method() & { std::cout << "on lvalue\n"; }
    void method() && { std::cout << "on rvalue\n"; }
};
```

then

```
auto obj = MyClass();
obj.method();            // invoke the lvalue version
std::move(obj).method(); // invode the rvalue version
```

---

> Is there a way to route/overload the method according to whether an object is a rvalue reference or not?

To be precise, which overloading is selected in overload resolution depends on whether the object to be called on is an lvalue or rvalue, not its type is rvalue reference or not. Types and [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) are two independent things.